# Spring boot 1.2.1 No qualifying bean of type found for dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have upgraded from spring boot version 1.1.5 to 1.2.1 and now I get `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.

I have simple main class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

and later I have repo

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String>, UserRepositoryCustom {

   ...


}
```

custom repo

```
public interface UserRepositoryCustom {
    // custom methods
}
```

and impl class.

Before updating spring boot version to 1.2.1 everything was working as expected.
I have read https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2237 and tried to remove `@Repository` annotation but without success. 
Am I missing something?
Thnx for help

EDIT stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.respositories.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
```

Comment: Please add the stracktrace and exception that you get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to enable the JPA repositories:

Either use the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation and specify the parameters (like base repositories) or add the property `spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true` to your application.properties file to activate the Spring Boot auto configuration for Spring Data JPA.

The `@Repository` annotation is not suitable for this usecase and can be removed safely.

If you have fulfilled all conditions and the repositories are still not configured, then you can try to add the Spring Boot Actuator module, and open the url http://yourserver.domain/autoconfig. This will give you all auto configurations and their state with the reason (active or inactive and the reason for that). Check that for the `JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration`, if it is active or not.

Comment: You definitely pointed me to right direction. I have MongoConfig class with @EnableMongoRepositories annotation and basePackages property. What is strange, annotation without basePackages property was not working on MongoConfig class, but was on Application class. And all of that was working without problem on spring-boot 1.1.5 version.

Comment: Ah, sorry, somehow i mixed JPA and Mongo. But the answer applies also to Mongo, just the property is called "spring.data.mongo.repositories.enabled".

Comment: And regarding the basePackages property: If you don't specify it, Spring will search the package of the class, where the annotation is specified, and all packages below that. So if you have the MongoConfig class in a subpackage, then you have to define the basePackage property to include packages above or beside your MongoConfig class.