# SpringBoot repository not found (Hibernate)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Hello I am creating simple webapp using spring-boot and hibernate.
**application.properties** file contains properties to db conneciton.
Bellow are my files:

**App context:**

```
package hbwc;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Customer entity:**

```
package hbwc.customer;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    protected Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Customer[id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
                id, firstName, lastName);
    }

 }
```

**Customer repository:**

```
package hbwc.customer;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {}
```

**CustomerController:**

```
package hbwc.customer;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping("/customers")
        public String index() {
        List<Customer> all = (List<Customer>) repository.findAll();
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

I am using gradlew to building and running this example. But I have problem while 
running it (**./gradlew run**). I got exception which told me that can't find my CustomerRepository.
**Stack trace:**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [hbwc.customer.CustomerRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Please give me some advices what is wrong with my code.

**application.properties(project root directory)**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/hbwc
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=baza1

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Comment: You need to have a data source configured and you need a impl (spring-data-jpa for example) of spring data on your class path. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

Comment: It is not Sufficient to have properties in application.properties file ?

Comment: Looking at the example here it looks okay https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/. You can try adding '@Repository' to your CustomerRepository interface or '@EnableJpaRepositories' to your Application config class. Neither of which are required according to the example but try it anyway.

Comment: Further to my comment above, see the following which suggests that @EnableJpaRepositories may, as suggested,  be the missing part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443222/spring-boot-1-2-1-no-qualifying-bean-of-type-found-for-dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any sort of component annotation on your repository class. Try adding @Repository or @Component. Then you should (assuming that component scan is enabled) be able to Autowire the repository into your controller.